# Unable to open file for reading [filename.pdf] yii2 swiftmailer

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer

I am trying to send an email with attachment when I used var_dump($filename)it returns the filename and gettype($filename) it returns string. but when I am trying to send an attachment it still returns Unable to open file for reading [filename.pdf] even if $file_attachment was looped I tried to change UploadedFile::getInstancesByName('file_attachment'); to UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('file_attachment'); but nothing happened. Please help me.

This is my controller

```
 if(Yii::$app->request->isPost){
            $email =  Yii::$app->request->post('email');
            $message = Yii::$app->request->post('message');
            $file_attachment = UploadedFile::getInstancesByName('file_attachment');
            if($file_attachment){
                $mail = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                ->setFrom(['myemail@gmail.com' => 'My Email'])
                ->setTo($email)
                ->setSubject('My Subject')
                ->setHtmlBody($message);
                foreach ($file_attachment as $file) {
                    $filename = $file->baseName. '.' . $file->extension;
                    $mail->attach($filename);
                }
                //$mail->send();

               //echo gettype($filename);
              // var_dump($filename);
                $mail->send();
            }else{
                $mail =  Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                ->setFrom(['myemail@gmail.com' => 'My Email'])
                ->setTo($email)
                ->setSubject('My Subject')
                ->setHtmlBody($message)
                ->send();
            }
        }
```

This is the view

```
   <?php 
      echo FileInput::widget([
      'name' => 'file_attachment',
       'attribute' => 'file_attachment',
       'options' => ['multiple' => true]
       ]);

   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `baseName` property of `yii\web\UploadedFile` contains the original filename but the file is not present on the server under its original filename. You need to use `tempName` property that contains path to the uploaded file on server.

Your for each cycle that attaches files to mail should look like:

```php
foreach ($file_attachment as $file) {
    $filename = $file->baseName. '.' . $file->extension;
    $mail->attach(
        $file->tempName,
       ['fileName' => $filename]
    );
}
```

It might also be a good idea to check `hasError` property of `yii\web\UploadedFile` before attempting to attach file to see if the upload was successful.

Also make sure that you've set `'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'` in you form options when you are not using `ActiveForm` with `ActiveField::fileInput()` otherwise the files might not be uploaded.